# Question mark at the end of GET url in Chrome Debugging

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app I'm sending a GET request to a backend server to fetch some data. This is how I create a destination URL:

```
get(config.PACKAGES_URL + '?uuid=' + uuid + '&type=P12&purpose=MAINTENANCE', {}, {Authorization: token})
```

and this `get` function is defined as

```
get = (url, params, headers) => (
fetch(`${url}?${queryString.stringify(params)}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
})
```

The URL is created properly, but Debugger shows me that it also has a question mark ( "?" ) at the very end. That messes up the request and causes the backend not being able to process it. Is there a way to remove that question mark? I suppose it's debugger related problem and when I would switch to release I wouldn't get this. I need to be on the debugger mode though.

**EDIT**: Got it fixed by moving the uuid, type and purpose from URL do BODY. So now it looks like this:

```
get(config.PACKAGES_URL,
    {
        uuid: uuid,
        type: 'P12',
        purpose: 'MAINTENANCE'
    }, {Authorization: token})
```

Comment: are running chrome js debug mode and can show your react request ?

Comment: also test your server side by something like postman

Comment: @nima_moradi Postman requests work as intended, with the same url that React tries to send (without the '?' of course). I am running js debug mode (I use Firefox for debugging), the request looks like the one from Postman, the only difference is this question mark